# SMTP password deletes itself from Outbound Email settings

Tags: drupal, email, smtp

I am configuring the latest version of CiviCRM (Drupal) to use Mailgun as an external SMTP service. When I go to `Administer > System Settings > Outbound Email`, enter the SMTP credentials, and click `Save & Send Test Email`, everything works great, I receive the test email, and the masked password continues to appear in the password field. If I then go to send a mailing, my emails all bounce with the error:

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Ema

When I return to the `Outbound Email` page, the masked password is now gone, and I'm unable to send another test without reentering the password. If I reenter the password and click `Save` instead of `Save & Send Test Email` the same thing happens. When I return to the `Outbound Email` page, the saved password is gone.

I didn't set up this CiviCRM installation, I'm just helping someone out with theirs. Is there a setting I'm missing that would account for this? Is it possible an overriding SMTP password is passed in as an environment variable somewhere or something?

Comment: Check in sites/default/civicrm.settings.php. Somebody may have set an override for smtp.

Comment: Also if it's a recent-ish version of civi check if civicrm.settings.php has CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS and CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS defined. If not you can use this tool to generate: https://civisettings.symbiotic.coop/

Comment: @Demerit There are cred and sign keys but nothing related to SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

I was incorrect, the password is not being deleted. It just requires a certain flag to be passed to load in the existing password, which is saved in the database.